# Passing string to ViewController wont show

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I am trying to get a very basic project completed; depending on the button, a different text appears on the second view. I have been on this for hours and it's come to the point I can't think of anything else to try. I've ran with a few suggestions on here, but I am having problems with the second ViewController actually getting the information.

I see that this question has been asked before, I just can't put it together, myself...

```
//ViewController.h



#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SuggestionViewController.h"
@class SuggestionViewController;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
SuggestionViewController * suggestionViewController;
}

- (IBAction)burger:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)pasta:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)chicken:(id)sender;


@end
```

-

```
//ViewController.m


#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SuggestionViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

NSString *valueTxt = @"example";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    suggestionViewController=[[SuggestionViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SuggestionViewController" bundle:nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)burger:(id)sender {
    //value1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Burger"];
    suggestionViewController.suggestionText = valueTxt;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bSe" sender:sender];


}

- (IBAction)pasta:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bSe" sender:sender];
   suggestionViewController.suggestionText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pasta"];
}

- (IBAction)chicken:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bSe" sender:sender];
    suggestionViewController.suggestionText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chicken"];
}
    @end
```

-

```
//SuggestionViewController.h

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "ViewController.h"

@interface SuggestionViewController : UIViewController


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* suggestionText;

@end
```

-

```
//SuggestionViewController.m

#import "SuggestionViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SuggestionViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *suLabel;


@end

@implementation SuggestionViewController
@synthesize suggestionText;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //SuggestionViewController *vc = [[SuggestionViewController alloc] init];
    //vc.suLabel.text = suggestionText;
    _suLabel.text = suggestionText;
} 

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }

@end
```

Comment: Are you using NIBs or a Storyboard?  You are allocating your new view controller using a NIB but then trying to segue to it - which implies a storyboard

Comment: Storyboard, yes... That part is likely copied to try and make it work, I didn't realize it had a separation though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `suggestionViewController` for good from your code. And implement the PrepareForSegue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    SuggestionViewController *suggestionViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    suggestionViewController.suggestionText = valueTxt;
}
```

You were setting the value to another instance of the SuggestionViewController and not the one that is created using the segue.

`prepareForSegue` for segue method is the place to pass values to view controllers created by segues.

Comment: Ok, I think I see a little better now, thanks. If you have 'prepareForSegue' is it literally just the preparation in case it's used? I hadn't even realized you could have it written in two parts. So when I 'self perfomSegue' I am asking it to go to prepare?

Comment: You can say that. It exactly to let you have an access to the Destination View Controller. to pass it value. or to change it's appearance animation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `suggestionViewController` instance that you see in your interface when you say `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bSe" sender:sender];` is not the same `suggestionViewController` instance that you have been retaining and configuring all this time.

What you want to do is implement `prepareForSegue` and perform all your configuration there. That is what it is for.

Either that, or don't use storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a storyboard, `performSegueWithIdentifier` will allocate a new instance of the destination view controller for you - so the one that you are creating doesn't get used.

You can change your property to store the string that you want to send and then set this on the destination in `prepareForSegue` -

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

- (IBAction)burger:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)pasta:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)chicken:(id)sender;


@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.m"
#import "SuggestionViewController.h"

@interface ViewController()

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *valueText;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)burger:(id)sender {
    self.valueText=@"Burger";
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bSe" sender:sender];


}

- (IBAction)pasta:(id)sender {
    self.valueText=@"pasta"
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bSe" sender:sender];
}

- (IBAction)chicken:(id)sender {
    self.valueText=@"chicken"
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bSe" sender:sender];
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"bSe"]) {
        SuggestionViewController *svc=(SuggestionViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        svc.suggestionText=self.valueText;
    }

@end
```